# Google play Games cannot sign-in Error 403

Tags: android, google-play-games

I have troubles trying to integrate Google Play Game Services to my game. I followed the tutorial and watched the video of "most 7 errors using google play games" and none of them was my case.

I have defined my Google services on the Developer Console. After that i have vinculed 2 apps, with the same package name that i have on manifest. I Used the keytool to take the 2 certificates fingerprint. Then, I adde my app_id to the manifest (only the 13 dígits).

And when I launch the application, it shows the splash of Google Play Games, asking me wich of my 2 google accounts I want to log in, I select it and then it asks me for permissions and finally when I accept, it shows me a popup error message saying: "Unknown issue with Google Play Services".

And the error in Log is this:

```
07-16 15:41:36.578: E/Volley(30175): [4704] tm.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2beta/apps/self?prettyPrint=false
07-16 15:41:36.598: E/ClientConnectionOperation(30175): Handling authorization failure
07-16 15:41:36.598: E/ClientConnectionOperation(30175): chb: Authorization failed: server returned error: Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.. See https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors for details.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have created another game services project to test and I have the same error.

If someone knows how to solve it, I will appreciate the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drive API is required for cloud saves, and you **may** need to enable it even if you don't intend to use cloud saving. It might also be required for some other functionality, but which exactly I am not sure.

It is harmless to enable it and some features of Play Games depend on it. It is much less painful to just enable it than to go hunting around for a reason not to :)

Comment: I can confirm that enabled the Drive API (I enabled the SDK for good measure too) gets rid of this message.

You cannot disable shared saves in the Google Dev Console so I guess it demands access even if you're not using it

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have not turned on Google Play Games in the developer Console

https://console.developers.google.com/

This is where you should have got your api key and where you have to turn on/off the various api's used in your app. be sure that the key you are using is registered to the same package name as your app..

Comment: I have 4 API's turned on:

Google Play App State
 
Google Play Game Management
 
Google Play Game Services
 
Google+ API

and I have tried to change the package or app_id in my manifest for another that does not exists, and the error is not the same, so it detects that my app_id and package are correct.

Comment: But for I understand, the Drive api and sdk is only if you want to integrate the application with Google Drive? I don't use any Google Drive feature, I only want to make sign-in, Games Achievements and Leaderboards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add the account to the testers account if the app is not published. While the app is on testing (development) you can only log In with testers accounts.