# ERROR: Unknown Issue with Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

This suddenly showed up over the past week. I have tried to revert my changes through my VCS, but the error seems to remain. I do not recall making any console changes either.

Error message

> Unknown Issue with Google Play Services

This appears after the sign in appears to go through. I am using the BaseGameActivity and following the tutorials.

Here is the full LogCat dump:

> 07-16 23:16:24.754    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife W/PopupManager?
>   You have not specified a View to use as content view for popups.
>   Falling back to the Activity content view which may not work properly
>   in future versions of the API. Use setViewForPopups() to set your
>   content view. 07-16 23:16:25.234    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   I/dalvikvm-heap? Grow heap (frag case) to 50.045MB for 40960016-byte
>   allocation 07-16 23:16:25.605    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper: Debug log enabled. 07-16 23:16:25.615
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper: onStart 07-16
>   23:16:25.615    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: Connecting client. 07-16 23:16:25.785
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife W/Adreno-GSL? :
>   Android framework reported version 2. So, don't force ES30 07-16
>   23:16:25.785    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife I/Adreno-EGL?
>   : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:
>   AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1_CL3869936_release_AU
>   (CL3869936)
>       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
>       Build Date: 12/09/13 Mon
>       Local Branch: mybranch2092625
>       Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.15
>       Local Patches: NONE
>       Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018 +  NOTHING 07-16 23:16:25.845    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/OpenGLRenderer? Enabling debug mode 0 07-16 23:16:25.875
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:
>   onConnectionFailed 07-16 23:16:25.875    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper: Connection failure: 07-16 23:16:25.875
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:    - code:
>   SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4) 07-16 23:16:25.875
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:    -
>   resolvable: true 07-16 23:16:25.875    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper:    - details:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=PendingIntent{422b4208: android.os.BinderProxy@422b41a8}}
>   07-16 23:16:25.875    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: WILL resolve because user initiated
>   sign-in. 07-16 23:16:25.875    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: resolving problem...
>   07-16 23:16:25.875    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=PendingIntent{422b4208: android.os.BinderProxy@422b41a8}}
>   07-16 23:16:25.875    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: Result has resolution. Starting it. 07-16 23:16:30.650
>   4304-4331/app.cheetah.petlife D/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 404K, 17%
>   free 48535K/58184K, paused 28ms, total 28ms 07-16 23:16:30.660
>   4304-4331/app.cheetah.petlife I/GAV3? Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No
>   campaign data found. 07-16 23:16:33.994
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:
>   onActivityResult: req=RC_RESOLVE, resp=RESULT_OK 07-16 23:16:33.994
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper: onAR:
>   Resolution was RESULT_OK, so connecting current client again. 07-16
>   23:16:33.994    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: Starting connection. 07-16 23:16:37.247
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:
>   onConnectionFailed 07-16 23:16:37.247    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper: Connection failure: 07-16 23:16:37.247
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:    - code:
>   INTERNAL_ERROR(8) 07-16 23:16:37.247    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper:    - resolvable: false 07-16 23:16:37.247
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper:    - details:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null} 07-16
>   23:16:37.257    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: WILL resolve because user initiated
>   sign-in. 07-16 23:16:37.257    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   D/GameHelper? GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: resolving problem...
>   07-16 23:16:37.257    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null} 07-16
>   23:16:37.257    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper?
>   GameHelper: resolveConnectionResult: result has no resolution. Giving
>   up. 07-16 23:16:37.257    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife W/GameHelper?
>   disconnect() called when client was already disconnected. 07-16
>   23:16:37.267    4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife
>   E/GooglePlayServicesUtil? Internal error occurred. Please see logs for
>   detailed information 07-16 23:16:37.367
>   4304-4304/app.cheetah.petlife D/GameHelper? GameHelper: Notifying
>   LISTENER of sign-in FAILURE (error)

No stack trace or any specific messages. I am not finding where these log files are either. I would think that would give me great insight as well.

I am running Android Studio 0.8.2. I have tried debug releases and both Play and manual signed APK installs. All the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and after many attempts, I found the solution for my case, and it was enabling the Drive API and Drive SDK in the Developers Console, as suggested in [Google play Games cannot sign-in Error 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783140/google-play-games-cannot-sign-in-error-403), although my error code was not 403, but exactly as yours.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You rock, that was exactly all that I needed to do. Logged into https://console.developers.google.com , went to APIs and enabled Drive API and Drive SDK (did not even need to configure them)

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by AVCarreiro, however, it didn't help me. If someone else has this problem and stumbles upon this thread, here are some things to try:

1. Obviously, AVCarreiro's answer
2. In the google play dev console, go to game services, click your project, and go to Game details on the left side. At the bottom of the page you will see a section called "API console project". Here it will tell you all the api's that need to be allowed for your project.
3. Make sure you're using the correct test account
4. Make sure your application is signed before testing
5. Try not using a debug version (that for some reason worked for me)

After making a signed (non-debug) apk and moving it to a device (with the correct test account) the services started working.